# Apache Lucene - How to update an existing index without concurrency issues?

Tags: lucene

I'm using Lucene Core 3.6.

I'm asking this within the context of a multi-user environment where many concurrent requests will be coming into the `IndexSearcher`.

Can I just create a new `IndexWriter` using the same `Directory` and `Analyzer` I used to originally populate the index and safely write to it? Will there be blocking, synchronization, or concurrency issues I have to be aware of?

From my reading I believe that the newly added document is available as soon as I open a new `IndexSearcher` however I've also read that for performance reasons I want to keep one `IndexSearcher` open for as long as possible. To me, this implies I have to keep track of when I write to the index so I can return a new `IndexSearcher` on the next request.

I would suspect my choice of `Directory` implementation has an effect on this. Till now I've only been using `RAMDirectory`.

EDIT: Updated the title to better clarify what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an SearchManager. Mike McCandless has a [blog post](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2011/11/near-real-time-readers-with-lucenes.html) about search managers and NRT managers which might be helpful.

There are various articles you can read online about how Lucene achieves near-real-time (NRT) index updates, but to answer your basic questions: only one IndexWriter should ever be open, but new readers are opened from that writer upon update. It's good to keep a reader open as long as possible, but since with NRT the updates come from memory, it's a pretty quick turnaround (generally tens of milliseconds).

Comment: Thanks for the link. That gentlemen's blog is a wealth of resources for this topic.